# How to parse a string in a file using Windows batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

content within the file

```
Submitting change 349.

Locking 1 files ...

add //ABC/BCA/DUL/test.txt#1

Change 349 submitted.
```

I want to parse the line 3 from the file and this is going to grow as many new files are added/updated/deleted

so its like 
add ..

update ..

delete..

add..

update..

delete..

Output should look like

```
File: test.txt

Action: Add

File Version: 1

Path: //ABC/BCA/DUL
```

Pls advice how to get these values using windows scripting

Comment: This makes no sense, please clean it up a bit. Also show what you've attempted before you ask. This isn't a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on your `"input file.txt"`

```
@echo off
(
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('find "//" ^< "input file.txt"') do (
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%c in ("%%b") do (
echo(File: %%~nxc
echo(
echo(Action: %%a
echo(
echo(File Version: %%d
echo(
echo(Path: %%~pb
echo(
)
)
)>"output file.txt"
pause
```

Comment: @ foxidrive Can the file details be "grouped/bundled" together so each file has it's own section to make it more readable?

something like this

File: test.txt
Action: Add
File Version: 1
Path: //ABC/BCA/DUL

File: test.txt
Action: Add
File Version: 1
Path: //ABC/BCA/DUL

Comment: I fixed the extra lines